# Create an iterator from a certain point

Tags: python

for example i got a list

```
L = [1,33,55,777,'abc'....]
```

i want to iterate it from a certain point like from the second element,this is what i used to do

```
for x in L[1:]:
    print(x)
```

thus works but made a shallow copy of part of the original list,or i can use the subscript

```
for x in range(1,len(L)):
    print(l[x])
```

is there a way in python to create an iterator in lowerer cost ?which may looks like this one:

```
for x in iter(L,1): #iter from index 1 to the end
    print(L[x])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from itertools import islice
for x in islice(L, 1, None): # start=1, stop=None
    print(x)
```